# Custom Popup Dialog Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

I'd like to create email dialog that has several inputs including message textbox plus some other custom info. I'd like it to display center screen over top of main page setting the opacity to like 50%.

do i create the pop up as anohter aspx page or panel?

Not sure what to use here, z-index, modalPopupExtender, Javascript, jquery. looking for easy and something stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into the **ModalPopupExtender** in the AJAX Toolkit.

You can also try creating the dialog with jQuery. If you decide to go that route, check out the jQuery UI dialog:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: +1, AJAX Control Toolkit is fantastically easy to use, especially for beginners

Comment: Actually you mean the [ModalPopupExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx) ;) Yes, i would recommend it too. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/ModalPopupExtender.aspx

Comment: I am experimenting with it currently. But with Master pages it seems to be taking a little longer to figure out, but none the less it is working and it was fairly easy even for the new guy. Just out of curiosity what is the most common way asp.net or python?

Comment: What do you mean by the most common way??

Comment: Well I am fairly new to this, but from browsing on the internet i usually see quite a few popups, just wondering what the vast majority use for creating them.

Comment: It really depends on which web application framework you use. JavaScript & jQuery solutions are probably the most common cross-platform approaches. Since you're using ASP.NET though, I would say that the most common solutions are those I suggested.